# Customize HTTP Upgrade request in libwebsockets

Tags: c++, http, websocket, libwebsockets

I'm using a [HTTP Upgrade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Upgrade) request to start a Websockets connection. Can I customize the body of this request by using libwebsockets in C++?

For example, I want to add a custom data field in the request body so that in the server, I can parse it and authorize the connection.

Comment: Do you actually mean the body of the request? The request is a get request so is not allowed to have a body. Normally you'd use the request headers to pass any authentication parameters

Comment: @AlanBirtles every HTTP request (including GET) is allowed to have body. Unusual, but not forbidden. That being said the standard recommends ignoring body for GET request. And so that is not a good idea anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so if I use request headers to authentication, is there any way I can customize it

Comment: I don't know much about this lib. But you can always move authentication to the websocket itself. It is not necessary to do it in handshake. I'm not even sure if that is a good idea. Wouldn't it be better to leave it as it is, and treat handshake as part of the transport layer without additional logic?

Comment: Don't know why but its what backend want, maybe they want the authentication before actual do handshake to prevent open too much connection. But I think it better to send HTTP request to authentication before do handshake, etc

Comment: five minutes of searching yields [this example](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/blob/0d76f0950aecaa420da2ab8f19baaf79111150da/minimal-examples-lowlevel/http-client/minimal-http-client-custom-headers/minimal-http-client-custom-headers.c#L38)

Comment: Thanks for the example. Success to add field to header of http upgrade request